# Outlook Rule for Email Listservs

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

How do you set up an Outlook receive rule for emails coming from listservs that seem to use a proxy of some sort ("on behalf of...)?

For example, there is a local news blog I'm subscribed to ARLnow.com. Emails received from them show up as "ARLnow.com" as Sender, subject as "Afternoon Update from ARLnow.com" and here's the tricky part, the basic header shows an ever-changing "noreply=arlnow.com@mail6.atl111.rsgsv.net" or " noreply=arlnow.com@mail169.suw121.mcdlv.net" series of addresses "on behalf of ARLnow.com noreply@arlnow.com".

I've used seemingly every option available as far as "sender is...", "body contains text...", header contains text...", etc. using "noreply@arlnow.com" or simply "arlnow.com" but that never seems to work. The only thing that works is to use the email proxy address, but that seems to change every other day, and is never used twice.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a known unsolvable problem?

EDIT

- Running Outlook 2016
- MailChimp is the subscription manager

Comment: The original address should be included in the message internet header. If we copy the internet header and paste it to notepad, can you see the original email address, which should be "noreply@arlnow.com"?

Comment: Original address is there: a dynamic address ending in either "mcdlv.net" or "rsgsv.net", which I've included in the "header includes text" condition to no avail. Nothing from the header that I've tried including in this condition has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "with specific words in the sender's address" rule and add the "noreply=arlnow.com@" to the word list.

Comment: No, that didn't work either.